# How do I avoid svg figure mutation on office 365 Word?

Tags: svg, ms-word, office365

I have this **svg image**:

[image]

When I insert it in an office 365 Word document, it imports it like this:

[image]

I have tried editing the document on the browser editor, but it does not allow svg images.

What is wrong with this? It is an SVG image, I don't understand how it can change the icons.

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" class="marks" width="575" height="414" viewBox="0 0 575 414"><rect width="575" height="414" fill="white"/><g fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" transform="translate(9,58)"><g class="mark-group role-frame root" role="graphics-object" aria-roledescription="group mark container"><g transform="translate(0,0)"><path class="background" aria-hidden="true" d="M0,0h0v0h0Z"/><g><g class="mark-group role-row-footer row_footer" role="graphics-object" aria-roledescription="group mark container"><g transform="translate(561,0)"><path class="background" aria-hidden="true" d="M0,0h0v150h0Z"/><g><g class="mark-group role-title"><g transform="translate(-6,75)"><path class="background" aria-hidden="true" d="M0,0h0v0h0Z" pointer-events="none"/><g><g class="mark-text role-title-text" role="graphics-symbol" aria-roledescription="title" aria-label="Title text '32L'" pointer-events="none"><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(90) translate(0,19)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="24px" fill="#000" opacity="1">32L</text></g></g><path class="foreground" aria-hidden="true" d="" pointer-events="none" display="none"/></g></g></g><path class="foreground" aria-hidden="true" d="" display="none"/></g><g transform="translate(561,179)"><path class="background" aria-hidden="true" d="M0,0h0v150h0Z"/><g><g class="mark-group role-title"><g transform="translate(-6,75)"><path class="background" aria-hidden="true" d="M0,0h0v0h0Z" pointer-events="none"/><g><g class="mark-text role-title-text" role="graphics-symbol" aria-roledescription="title" aria-label="Title text '32R'" pointer-events="none"><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(90) translate(0,19)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="24px" fill="#000" opacity="1">32R</text></g></g><path class="foreground" aria-hidden="true" d="" pointer-events="none" display="none"/></g></g></g><path class="foreground" aria-hidden="true" d="" display="none"/></g></g><g class="mark-group role-column-footer column_footer" role="graphics-object" aria-roledescription="group mark container"><g transform="translate(0,330)"><path class="background" aria-hidden="true" d="M0,0h500v0h-500Z"/><g><g class="mark-group role-axis" role="graphics-symbol" aria-roledescription="axis" aria-label="X-axis for a utc scale with values from Sunday, 01 January 2012, 8:25:00 PM UTC to Sunday, 01 January 2012, 9:09:00 PM UTC"><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)"><path class="background" aria-hidden="true" d="M0,0h0v0h0Z" pointer-events="none"/><g><g class="mark-rule role-axis-tick" pointer-events="none"><line transform="translate(0,0)" x2="0" y2="5" stroke="#888" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(57,0)" x2="0" y2="5" stroke="#888" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(114,0)" x2="0" y2="5" stroke="#888" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(170,0)" x2="0" y2="5" stroke="#888" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(227,0)" x2="0" y2="5" stroke="#888" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(284,0)" x2="0" y2="5" stroke="#888" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(341,0)" x2="0" y2="5" stroke="#888" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(398,0)" x2="0" y2="5" stroke="#888" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(455,0)" x2="0" y2="5" stroke="#888" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/></g><g class="mark-text role-axis-label" pointer-events="none"><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(0,18)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14px" fill="#000" opacity="1">20:25</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(56.81818181818181,18)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14px" fill="#000" opacity="1">20:30</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(113.63636363636363,18)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14px" fill="#000" opacity="1">20:35</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(170.45454545454544,18)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14px" fill="#000" opacity="1">20:40</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(227.27272727272725,18)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14px" fill="#000" opacity="1">20:45</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(284.0909090909091,18)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14px" fill="#000" opacity="1">20:50</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(340.9090909090909,18)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14px" fill="#000" opacity="1">20:55</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(397.7272727272727,18)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14px" fill="#000" opacity="1">21:00</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(454.5454545454545,18)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14px" fill="#000" opacity="1">21:05</text></g><g class="mark-rule role-axis-domain" pointer-events="none"><line transform="translate(0,0)" x2="500" y2="0" stroke="#888" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/></g></g><path class="foreground" aria-hidden="true" d="" pointer-events="none" display="none"/></g></g></g><path class="foreground" aria-hidden="true" d="" display="none"/></g></g><g class="mark-group role-scope cell" role="graphics-object" aria-roledescription="group mark container"><g transform="translate(0,0)"><path class="background" aria-hidden="true" d="M0.5,0.5h500v150h-500Z" stroke="#ddd"/><g><g class="mark-group role-axis" role="graphics-symbol" aria-roledescription="axis" aria-label="X-axis for a utc scale with values from Sunday, 01 January 2012, 8:25:00 PM UTC to Sunday, 01 January 2012, 9:09:00 PM UTC"><g transform="translate(0.5,150.5)"><path class="background" aria-hidden="true" d="M0,0h0v0h0Z" pointer-events="none"/><g><g class="mark-rule role-axis-grid" pointer-events="none"><line transform="translate(0,0)" x2="0" y2="-150" stroke="#ddd" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(57,0)" x2="0" y2="-150" stroke="#ddd" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(114,0)" x2="0" y2="-150" stroke="#ddd" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(170,0)" x2="0" y2="-150" stroke="#ddd" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(227,0)" x2="0" y2="-150" stroke="#ddd" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(284,0)" x2="0" y2="-150" stroke="#ddd" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(341,0)" x2="0" y2="-150" stroke="#ddd" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(398,0)" x2="0" y2="-150" stroke="#ddd" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(455,0)" x2="0" y2="-150" stroke="#ddd" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/></g></g><path class="foreground" aria-hidden="true" d="" pointer-events="none" display="none"/></g></g><g class="mark-rule role-mark child_layer_0_marks" role="graphics-symbol" aria-roledescription="rule mark container"><line transform="translate(0,4.411764705882353)" x2="11.363636363636363" y2="0" stroke="#4c78a8" stroke-width="3"/><line transform="translate(0,13.23529411764706)" x2="34.090909090909086" y2="0" stroke="#4c78a8" stroke-width="3"/><line transform="translate(22.727272727272727,22.058823529411768)" x2="45.454545454545446" y2="0" stroke="#4c78a8" stroke-width="3"/><line transform="translate(56.81818181818181,39.70588235294118)" x2="34.09090909090909" y2="0" stroke="#f58518" stroke-width="3"/><line transform="translate(397.7272727272727,136.76470588235296)" x2="22.727272727272805" y2="0" stroke="#4c78a8" stroke-width="3"/><line transform="translate(477.2727272727273,145.58823529411765)" x2="22.72727272727269" y2="0" stroke="#4c78a8" stroke-width="3"/></g><g class="mark-text role-mark child_layer_1_marks" role="graphics-object" aria-roledescription="text mark container"><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(23.363636363636363,7.411764705882353)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="11px" fill="#4c78a8">AEA9117</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(46.090909090909086,16.235294117647058)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="11px" fill="#4c78a8">AEA7319</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(80.18181818181817,25.058823529411768)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="11px" fill="#4c78a8">AJU451</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(102.9090909090909,42.70588235294118)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="11px" fill="#f58518">AEA13QZ</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(432.4545454545455,139.76470588235296)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="11px" fill="#4c78a8">AEA83LM</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(512,148.58823529411765)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="11px" fill="#4c78a8">IBE31WK</text></g><g class="mark-text role-mark child_layer_2_marks" role="graphics-object" aria-roledescription="text mark container"><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(3.3636363636363633,11.411764705882353)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="20px" fill="#4c78a8">✈</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(26.090909090909086,20.235294117647058)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="20px" fill="#4c78a8">✈</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(60.18181818181817,29.058823529411768)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="20px" fill="#4c78a8">✈</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(82.9090909090909,46.70588235294118)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="20px" fill="#f58518">✈</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(412.4545454545455,143.76470588235296)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="20px" fill="#4c78a8">✈</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(492,152.58823529411765)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="20px" fill="#4c78a8">✈</text></g></g><path class="foreground" aria-hidden="true" d="" display="none"/></g><g transform="translate(0,179)"><path class="background" aria-hidden="true" d="M0.5,0.5h500v150h-500Z" stroke="#ddd"/><g><g class="mark-group role-axis" role="graphics-symbol" aria-roledescription="axis" aria-label="X-axis for a utc scale with values from Sunday, 01 January 2012, 8:25:00 PM UTC to Sunday, 01 January 2012, 9:09:00 PM UTC"><g transform="translate(0.5,150.5)"><path class="background" aria-hidden="true" d="M0,0h0v0h0Z" pointer-events="none"/><g><g class="mark-rule role-axis-grid" pointer-events="none"><line transform="translate(0,0)" x2="0" y2="-150" stroke="#ddd" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(57,0)" x2="0" y2="-150" stroke="#ddd" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(114,0)" x2="0" y2="-150" stroke="#ddd" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(170,0)" x2="0" y2="-150" stroke="#ddd" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(227,0)" x2="0" y2="-150" stroke="#ddd" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(284,0)" x2="0" y2="-150" stroke="#ddd" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(341,0)" x2="0" y2="-150" stroke="#ddd" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(398,0)" x2="0" y2="-150" stroke="#ddd" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/><line transform="translate(455,0)" x2="0" y2="-150" stroke="#ddd" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/></g></g><path class="foreground" aria-hidden="true" d="" pointer-events="none" display="none"/></g></g><g class="mark-rule role-mark child_layer_0_marks" role="graphics-symbol" aria-roledescription="rule mark container"><line transform="translate(34.090909090909086,30.88235294117647)" x2="45.45454545454546" y2="0" stroke="#4c78a8" stroke-width="3"/><line transform="translate(56.81818181818181,48.52941176470589)" x2="68.18181818181819" y2="0" stroke="#4c78a8" stroke-width="3"/><line transform="translate(113.63636363636363,57.352941176470594)" x2="45.45454545454547" y2="0" stroke="#4c78a8" stroke-width="3"/><line transform="translate(113.63636363636363,66.17647058823529)" x2="68.18181818181819" y2="0" stroke="#4c78a8" stroke-width="3"/><line transform="translate(136.36363636363635,75)" x2="68.18181818181822" y2="0" stroke="#4c78a8" stroke-width="3"/><line transform="translate(90.9090909090909,83.82352941176471)" x2="147.72727272727275" y2="0" stroke="#f58518" stroke-width="3"/><line transform="translate(181.8181818181818,92.64705882352942)" x2="79.54545454545456" y2="0" stroke="#4c78a8" stroke-width="3"/><line transform="translate(193.1818181818182,101.47058823529412)" x2="90.90909090909093" y2="0" stroke="#4c78a8" stroke-width="3"/><line transform="translate(227.27272727272725,110.29411764705883)" x2="79.54545454545456" y2="0" stroke="#4c78a8" stroke-width="3"/><line transform="translate(250,119.11764705882354)" x2="79.5454545454545" y2="0" stroke="#f58518" stroke-width="3"/><line transform="translate(272.7272727272727,127.94117647058823)" x2="79.54545454545462" y2="0" stroke="#4c78a8" stroke-width="3"/></g><g class="mark-text role-mark child_layer_1_marks" role="graphics-object" aria-roledescription="text mark container"><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(91.54545454545455,33.88235294117647)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="11px" fill="#4c78a8">AEA71KK</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(137,51.52941176470589)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="11px" fill="#4c78a8">AEA1506</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(171.0909090909091,60.352941176470594)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="11px" fill="#4c78a8">AEA1518</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(193.8181818181818,69.17647058823529)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="11px" fill="#4c78a8">AEA1142</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(216.54545454545456,78)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="11px" fill="#4c78a8">IBE3255</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(250.63636363636365,86.82352941176471)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="11px" fill="#f58518">AEA54VD</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(273.3636363636364,95.64705882352942)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="11px" fill="#4c78a8">AEA7160</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(296.0909090909091,104.47058823529412)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="11px" fill="#4c78a8">IBE32KH</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(318.8181818181818,113.29411764705883)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="11px" fill="#4c78a8">AEA18AX</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(341.5454545454545,122.11764705882354)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="11px" fill="#f58518">AEA13QZ</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(364.2727272727273,130.94117647058823)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="11px" fill="#4c78a8">IBE32GT</text></g><g class="mark-text role-mark child_layer_2_marks" role="graphics-object" aria-roledescription="text mark container"><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(71.54545454545455,37.88235294117647)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="20px" fill="#4c78a8">✈</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(117,55.52941176470589)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="20px" fill="#4c78a8">✈</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(151.0909090909091,64.3529411764706)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="20px" fill="#4c78a8">✈</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(173.8181818181818,73.17647058823529)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="20px" fill="#4c78a8">✈</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(196.54545454545456,82)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="20px" fill="#4c78a8">✈</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(230.63636363636365,90.82352941176471)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="20px" fill="#f58518">✈</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(253.36363636363637,99.64705882352942)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="20px" fill="#4c78a8">✈</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(276.0909090909091,108.47058823529412)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="20px" fill="#4c78a8">✈</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(298.8181818181818,117.29411764705883)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="20px" fill="#4c78a8">✈</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(321.5454545454545,126.11764705882354)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="20px" fill="#f58518">✈</text><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(344.2727272727273,134.94117647058823)" font-family="Ubuntu" font-size="20px" fill="#4c78a8">✈</text></g></g><path class="foreground" aria-hidden="true" d="" display="none"/></g></g><g class="mark-group role-legend" role="graphics-symbol" aria-roledescription="legend" aria-label="Symbol legend titled 'go around' for fill color and stroke color with 2 values: 0, 1"><g transform="translate(0,-53)"><path class="background" aria-hidden="true" d="M0,0h55v29h-55Z" pointer-events="none"/><g><g class="mark-group role-legend-entry"><g transform="translate(0,16)"><path class="background" aria-hidden="true" d="M0,0h0v0h0Z" pointer-events="none"/><g><g class="mark-group role-scope" role="graphics-object" aria-roledescription="group mark container"><g transform="translate(0,0.25)"><path class="background" aria-hidden="true" d="M0,0h21.5615234375v12.5h-21.5615234375Z" pointer-events="none" opacity="1"/><g><g class="mark-symbol role-legend-symbol" pointer-events="none"><path transform="translate(6,6)" d="M5,0A5,5,0,1,1,-5,0A5,5,0,1,1,5,0" fill="#4c78a8" stroke="#4c78a8" stroke-width="1.5" opacity="1"/></g><g class="mark-text role-legend-label" pointer-events="none"><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(16,9)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10px" fill="#000" opacity="1">0</text></g></g><path class="foreground" aria-hidden="true" d="" pointer-events="none" display="none"/></g><g transform="translate(33,0.25)"><path class="background" aria-hidden="true" d="M0,0h21.5615234375v12.5h-21.5615234375Z" pointer-events="none" opacity="1"/><g><g class="mark-symbol role-legend-symbol" pointer-events="none"><path transform="translate(6,6)" d="M5,0A5,5,0,1,1,-5,0A5,5,0,1,1,5,0" fill="#f58518" stroke="#f58518" stroke-width="1.5" opacity="1"/></g><g class="mark-text role-legend-label" pointer-events="none"><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(16,9)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10px" fill="#000" opacity="1">1</text></g></g><path class="foreground" aria-hidden="true" d="" pointer-events="none" display="none"/></g></g></g><path class="foreground" aria-hidden="true" d="" pointer-events="none" display="none"/></g></g><g class="mark-text role-legend-title" pointer-events="none"><text text-anchor="start" transform="translate(0,9)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="11px" font-weight="bold" fill="#000" opacity="1">go around</text></g></g><path class="foreground" aria-hidden="true" d="" pointer-events="none" display="none"/></g></g></g><path class="foreground" aria-hidden="true" d="" display="none"/></g></g></g></svg>
```

Edit 1: posting the svg code text.

Comment: The airplane is an Emoji: https://emojipedia.org/search/?q=airplane

Comment: Yes @Danny'365CSI'Engelman thats funny, but how do I avoid Word modifying the original SVG image?

Comment: You have to dig into the SVG, that is where (we now presume) the Emoji is used. And I suspect there is a Font-file involved as well. But without source code there isn't much else to say. Personally I would not use SVGs in Word... one XML format inside another.. I'd stick to binary images.

Comment: But how does word modify a svg image when it is imported? this is the weirdest thing i have ever witnessed in word.

Comment: Word doesn't modify anything; it just displays a character from a Unicode set; that is why I suspect a custom font-file or something is in play... show the SVG source code

Comment: mmm what else could I upload so you can see more in detail whats going on? @Danny'365CSI'Engelman

Comment: The SVG source code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233883/discussion-between-peter-la-anguila-and-danny-365csi-engelman).

Comment: Your SVG file is a text file; just like an HTML file. Paste the content in your post

Comment: It is now posted @Danny'365CSI'Engelman. Please, if you could jump in the chat that would be class!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SVG is using a Unicode character for the airplane.

[image]

If Word doesn't show it; then Word doesn't have the Ubuntu font and defaults to the default (same unicode) airplane character:

[image]

I say (again); don't use SVGs in Word; convert to a binary image

Comment: Okay I will have a look at the svg to binary converters and how to insert them in word. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Online: https://www.google.com/search?q=svg+2+png Depending on your workflow, automate it: https://www.google.com/search?q=svg+2+png+gulp

Comment: I need it to be a vector image and as far as I now png is not vectorized :( @Danny'365CSI'Engelman